# How to load file to ArrayList from src folder

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I have been trying a lot of things and I just ready to ask for some help. if this is not enough info please let me know. I have tried `Scanner`, `BufferReader`, etc from searching posts with no luck.

I have the file `words.txt` right in the src directory.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    /*
     * CLASS THAT HANDLES GETTING AND SETTING THE SECRET WORD RANDOMLY
     */

    public class secretWord {
        private ArrayList theWordList;
        private Scanner scanner; //Used to read the file into the array
        private Random random; //Generates a random number index for choosing a random array element
        private int randomIndex; //Holds the random index generated
        ArrayList theSecretWord= new ArrayList(); //The secret word converted to char[] for use in the program
        String tempSecretWord; //Secret word selected as string

        //Constructor: runs methods to create arraylist of words then select a random element for thesecretword
        public secretWord(){
            createArray();
            getSecretWord();
        }
        //Creates an ArrayList of words from file
        private void createArray(){
            theWordList= new ArrayList();
            String file= getClass().getResource("words.txt").getPath();
            File f= new File(file);
            try{
            Scanner scanner= new Scanner(f);

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                theWordList.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                scanner.close();
            }
        }
        //Selects a random number from the ArrayList to use as the secret word
        private void getSecretWord(){
            random= new Random();
            randomIndex= random.nextInt(theWordList.size());
            theSecretWord.add(theWordList.get(randomIndex).toUpperCase());
        }
        //Removes the secretWord and gets a new one for another play
        void refreshWord(){
            theSecretWord.clear();
            getSecretWord();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at secretWord.createArray(secretWord.java:27)
 at secretWord.<init>(secretWord.java:21)
 at theFrame.<init>(theFrame.java:33)
 at theGame.main(theGame.java:6)

Comment: When i use Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File(words.txt)); I get file not found exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the top level ContextClassLoader to get the file.

```
     InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("words.txt");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line instead:

```
String file= getClass().getResource("words.txt").getFile();
```

Note the difference between path and file. And start your Java class names with capital letters, this is a convention.